# why apache2 server and mysql is not starting in XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, xampp, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to start/restart my `apache server` and `MySQL` in the `xampp` by using the terminal in `ubuntu 18.04`.

The **Commands** which I used to restart is :

```
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
   sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

I have tried many solutions already.
can anyone give me the idea to start `MySQL` and `apache server`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With limited info provided, your system is probably on systemd, so you can restart using:

```
service apache2 restart
service mysql restart
```

Or

```
systemctl restart apache2.service
systemctl restart mysql.service
```

Comment: Thanks @Wadih M. . I just uninstalled my XAMPP and reinstalled. Then I gave the commands that I used before.  My Apache server and MySQL  are working fine now.